# Is it possible to keep node.js and python codes together?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, multithreading, dashboard

Suppose I build a back end with node.js.
I also build a dashboard that shows analysed dataset with python (seaborn or matplotlib etc).
the front end is built with react.js

Is it possible to integrate the python codes with the JavaScript codes so that the dashboard is visible on the website?

Comment: What do you mean? Browser can't execute python code. However in your NodeJS backend you could access os and run when necessary "python -m yourpythonscript.py"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, We can Integrate Python in web throw **[WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly)**, WebAssembly is now standard language in web along with HTML/CSS/JS, Where we can integrate other language code to web browser in binary form. Refer this [issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly) for compiling python code to WebAssembly.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you build your dashboard. You can try using react-chartjs and get data from running your python script on back end.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use Docker or containerd to run different languages on one machine. The services visit each other by their names though http restful api. Use nginx for routing different url.